# pg_dump query LOCK_TABLE on Hasura

Tags: postgresql, heroku, hasura

I'm trying to get a backup of my database using
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups

But when I run this command heroku pg:backups:capture --app [app_name], I get the following error:

```
 ▸    An error occurred and the backup did not finish.
 ▸
 ▸    waiting for upload to complete
 ▸    pg_dump: error: query was: LOCK TABLE "topology"."topology" IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
 ▸    upload finished successfully
 ▸    waiting for pg_dump to complete
 ▸    pg_dump finished with errors
```

When I look at the logs, I get the following:

```
=== Backup Logs
2020-07-15 20:39:51 +0000 pg_dump: last built-in OID is 16383
2020-07-15 20:39:51 +0000 pg_dump: reading extensions
2020-07-15 20:39:51 +0000 pg_dump: identifying extension members
2020-07-15 20:39:51 +0000 pg_dump: reading schemas
2020-07-15 20:39:51 +0000 pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
2020-07-15 20:39:51 +0000 pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for schema topology
2020-07-15 20:39:51 +0000 waiting for upload to complete
2020-07-15 20:39:51 +0000 pg_dump: error: query was: LOCK TABLE "topology"."topology" IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
2020-07-15 20:39:52 +0000 upload finished successfully
2020-07-15 20:39:52 +0000 waiting for pg_dump to complete
2020-07-15 20:39:52 +0000 pg_dump finished with errors
```

I don't have a table called "topology", which is why I'm confused why I'm having this error. I really would like to get backups using Heroku rather than pg_dump, because then I can simply plug the backup's Database URL into a new Hasura GraphQL engine instance.

Does anyone know why I might be getting this error>

Answer (score 1):

That table must come from the `postgis_topology` extension.

`pg_dump` does not dump objects from an extension, but since `topology.topology` is marked as an [extension configuration table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html#EXTEND-EXTENSIONS-CONFIG-TABLES), its contents are dumped.

You get the error because the user has no `SELECT` rights on that table.

Several options you can try:

- ```
  DROP EXTENSION postgis_topology;
  ```

  You need to be a superuser for that, but I am sure that Heroku offers a way to do that.
- Run `pg_dump` with a user that has permissions to `SELECT` from the table.
- Try to exclude the table from the backup; not sure if that will work:

  ```
  pg_dump --exclude-table topology.topology dbname
  ```

Comment: Heroku doesn't allow access to superuser unfortunately: https://help.heroku.com/E10ZZ6IJ/why-can-t-i-use-third-party-tools-to-replicate-my-heroku-postgres-database-to-a-non-heroku-database

How do I create a user with the permission to SELECT from the topology table?

Comment: If I DROP EXTENSION, will I lose all my postgis_topology data?

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-dropextension.html, "Dropping an extension causes its component objects to be dropped as well."

Comment: Probably. You can try to drop the extension without `CASCADE`, then you will get an error message that contains objects that would be removed along with the extension.

Comment: I'm in the exact same boat with PostGIS on Heroku Postgres. Did you ever find a solution?